# simple python calculator won't run

Tags: python

Ok, what is wrong with my code? I press run and it doesn't give me anything. at get_num it says "too many positional arguments" and after that its just having issues. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
it says "no value for num 1 argument in function to call" and "no value for num 2 argument in function to call" "unused variable answer"

```
def main(): #control
  operation()
  get_num(operation)
  if operation == "+":
    answer = addition()
  elif operation == "*":
   answer = multiplication()
  elif operation == "-":
    answer = subtraction()
  else:
    answer = division()

def operation(): #prompts the user to enter a mathematical symbol & returns that symbol
 print("Enter one of the symbols when asked what operation you would like to preform")
operation = input("Would you like to multiply (*), add (+), subtract (-), or divide(/)? ")
return operation

def get_num(): #prompts the user to enter a single integers & returns that value
  print("Enter two numbers you would like to calculate")
  num1 = float(input("What is the first number you want to calculate? "))
  num2 = float(input("What is the second number you want to calculate? "))
  return num1
  return num2

 def addition(num1, num2):  #performs addition of the 2 numbers & returns the sum
   addition = num1 + num2
   return addition

def subtraction(num1, num2):  #performs subtraction of the second number from the first & returns the difference
  subtraction = num1 - num2
  return subtraction

def multiplication(num1, num2):  #performs multiplication of the 2 numbers & returns the product
 multiplication = num1 * num2
 return multiplication

def division(num1, num2): #if the second number is not zero, performs division of the first number (numerator) by the second number (denominator) and returns the quotient; if the second number is zero, doe not perform the division, but displays a message and returns a zero
  division = num1 / num2
  return division
   if num2 == "0":
    print("Error, cannot divide by 0")

 def show_answer(answer):  #displays the answer from the operation
 if operation == '*':
  print("The answer for your problem is", multiplication)
  elif operation == '-':
   print("The answer for your problem is", subtraction)
  elif operation == '+':
   print("The answer for your problem is", addition)
   elif operation == '/':
    print("The answer for your problem is", division)
   else:
   print("error")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey your program is written in neat manner but you need to pass the variable to the function ..... You can't define global variable like this

Comment: How do I do that? I'm super new to this, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the problems I see with your question/code:

1. Your code is poorly indented. I can't really try your code because of all of this weird indentions you have.
2. Your function call must have the same amount of argument like when you defined it `func(x, y)` must always be declared with 2 variables like `func('Hello', 'World')`
3. `return`returns a data but doesn't save itself. You must assign the value to a variable if you have a use for that data.
4. You don't quite understand local and global scopes of variables

Anyway avoid asking "why is my code not working" questions

Try this code:

```
def main(): #control
    operation = operate()
    num1, num2 = get_num()
    if operation == "+":
        answer = addition(num1, num2)
    elif operation == "*":
        answer = multiplication(num1, num2)
    elif operation == "-":
        answer = subtraction(num1, num2)
    elif operation == "/":
        answer = division(num1, num2)
    else:
        print ("Invalid Operation")
    show_answer(answer)

def operate(): #prompts the user to enter a mathematical symbol & returns that symbol
    print("Enter one of the symbols when asked what operation you would like to preform")
    operation = input("Would you like to multiply (*), add (+), subtract (-), or divide(/)? ")
    return operation

def get_num(): #prompts the user to enter a single integers & returns that value
    print("Enter two numbers you would like to calculate")
    num1 = float(input("What is the first number you want to calculate? "))
    num2 = float(input("What is the second number you want to calculate? "))
    return num1, num2

def addition(num1, num2):  #performs addition of the 2 numbers & returns the sum
    addition = num1 + num2
    return addition

def subtraction(num1, num2):  #performs subtraction of the second number from the first & returns the difference
    subtraction = num1 - num2
    return subtraction

def multiplication(num1, num2):  #performs multiplication of the 2 numbers & returns the product
    multiplication = num1 * num2
    return multiplication

def division(num1, num2): #if the second number is not zero, performs division of the first number (numerator) by the second number (denominator) and returns the quotient; if the second number is zero, doe not perform the division, but displays a message and returns a zero
    try:
        division = num1 / num2
        return division
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print ("Error, cannot be divided by 0")

def show_answer(answer):
    print ("The answer for your problem is", answer)

main()
```

You can also just change your else-if statement for your divison to check whether the value of num2 is 0:

```
elif operation == '/':
    if num2 == 0:
        return ('Error, cannot be divided by 0')
    else:
        answer = division(num1, num2)
```

Comment: Updated my answer. Try the code above, review about how to define and use functions and local and global variables. Also a general rule is to use 4 space for indentions or more if you want.

Comment: I'm not able to get the error message to print when trying to divide by 0 still

Comment: Oh try my updated answer. It was because you called return before checking if the value of num2 is 0. Once `return`is called, it automatically exits the loop or function thus ignoring the next line of codes. Before returning the answer, check if `num == 0` first.

Comment: https://repl.it/NkrV/3 I think I did what you said, but I'm still getting the error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 55, in <module>
  File "python", line 17, in main
  File "python", line 49, in division
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero"

Comment: Then I guess you could just raise and exception. Try it again

Comment: Are you using python 3.6.1? ValueError isn't showing up on mine

Comment: Yes I am using 3.x. Try raising ZeroDivisonError not ValueError

Comment: If you don't want to call `show_answer()` incase of zero division. Just change your elif statement and check whether num2 is equal to 0 before even calling the division() function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you wrote `get_num(operation)` but then your function has 0 arguments: `def get_num():`

Answer (score 0):

Area for improvement:

- Python is a scripting language, so you must call the main() function at the bottom to kick it off
- use `raw_input("message")` rather than `input("mesage")` and convert it yourself using `operator = str(raw_input("message"))`
- You are calling `get_num(operation)` but `operation()` is a function, not a value. Maybe you should store the return value of `get_num(operation)` into a variable like `operator = get_num(operation)`

Here is how I would make some improvements to your code:

```
def main(): #control
    operator = operation()
    nums = get_num()

    if operator == '+':
        answer = addition(nums[0], nums[1])

    elif operator == '*':
        answer = multiplication(nums[0], nums[1])

    elif operator == '-':
        answer = subtraction(nums[0], nums[1])

    elif operator == '/':
        answer = division(nums[0], nums[1])

    else:
        raise ValueError("'" + operator + "' Operand not recognized")

    # Display result
    answer = str(answer)
    print(str(nums[0]) + operator + str(nums[1]) + " = " + answer)

def operation(): #prompts the user to enter a mathematical symbol & returns that symbol
    print("Enter one of the symbols when asked what operation you would like to preform")

    operator = raw_input("Would you like to multiply (*), add (+), subtract (-), or divide(/)? ")

    # Convert it to a string
    return str(operator)

# NOTE - no need to pass the operator
def get_num(): #prompts the user to enter a single integers & returns that value
    print("Enter two numbers you would like to calculate")
    num1 = float(raw_input("What is the first number you want to calculate? "))
    num2 = float(raw_input("What is the second number you want to calculate? "))

    # NOTE - Return as an array rather than 2 return statements
    return [num1, num2]

def addition(num1, num2):  #performs addition of the 2 numbers & returns the sum
    addition = num1 + num2
    return addition

def subtraction(num1, num2):  #performs subtraction of the second number from the first & returns the difference
    subtraction = num1 - num2
    return subtraction

def multiplication(num1, num2):  #performs multiplication of the 2 numbers & returns the product
    multiplication = num1 * num2
    return multiplication

def division(num1, num2): #if the second number is not zero, performs division of the first number (numerator) by the second number (denominator) and returns the quotient; if the second number is zero, doe not perform the division, but displays a message and returns a zero

    # NOTE - Throw an error if denominator is 0
    if num2 == 0:
        raise ValueError("Divistion by zero")

    division = num1 / num2
    return division


# Remember to call main() to kick off the program
main()
```